# How to display <div> or message only to visitors who came from specified URL (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

What javascript code should I add? I want a certain  (short message) to show only to visitors who came from one webpage (url, not whole domain). This  should not appear (hidden) to other visitors through any links or search engines.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You need to find the referer. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Comment: did you look at 'document.referrer'?

Comment: And as a sidenote, `document.referrer` is notoriously unreliable, and is one of the many reasons you generally shouldn't be doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You could check [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) for a specific page:

```
if (document.referrer == "http://www.example.com/somepage") {
    // display message
}
```